# vFAT flash drives insist on only being writable by root

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, fstab, vfat

All the usual advice on editing `/etc/fstab` doesn't work.  My current fstab looks something like the following:

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/2D06-9C4C    /media/pi/TWILIGHT  vfat    user,auto,uid=pi,gid=pi,umask=000   0   0`

However, it still demands root permissions after I mount it.

Most telling is when I `ls -la` on `/media/pi/`: when the drive is unmounted, the folder permissions are pi/adm.  After I mount the drive, it is for root/root.

- Unmounted: `drwxrwxr-x   2 pi   adm  4096 Nov 22 16:31  TWILIGHT/`
- Mounted: `drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 32768 Dec 31  1969  TWILIGHT/`

The two other changes are that the mount point loses a `w` in the permissions when mounted and that the modification date moves to 31-DEC-1969.  That specific date makes me think something is going very wrong.

#### How things should work

The flash drive is writable by user `pi` and it auto-mounts regardless of whether it is plugged in during boot or after.

Comment: Try replacing `pi` in the `uid=` and `gid=` with the numeric values

Comment: That didn’t work, either. Neither did commenting out the lines from fstab and letting it mount with the default values.